# Multiplying two columns In Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I want to multiply two columns in a query

Example : Column A * Column B and have the result be displayed in Column C

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a table `YourTable` containing the columns `A` and `B` and that the columns `A` and `B` also should be displayed in the resulting query.

So here it is:

`Select A, B, A * B As C From YourTable`

If not, use just this:

`Select A * B As C From YourTable`

Comment: What if I have a table containing A and a different table containing B? There is no way to add them while in the query?

Comment: You have to build a relation between these tables in your query, a so called `Join`. Therefore both tables need to contain a column with the same logic content, like a BookID for example.